# How to enable tabbing for propterty grid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

Does anybody know how to enable tabbing for a property grid?

Right know when I select a property and press tab the input field for that property is selected. If i press tab again the control loses focus.

Instead I want to focus the `next property` then the assigned `input field` then the `next property` then the assigned `input field` again and so on...

thank you.

Comment: You can't change that. You need to press ESCAPE, not TAB, when the focus is on the value to give the focus back to the grid item. The focus will then stay in the grid and you can keep navigating in it.

Comment: Oh my god... youre right. MS cant be serious ?!